# How to set the default size in pixels of dialog in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

I want to set the default size in pixels of dialog, say it is 640 pixel width and 384 pixel height. what I mean by the `default` is that when the first time the `CXXXDlg::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)` is called, the value of `cx` is 640 and the value of `cy` is 384. scene the default size of the dialog is in dialog units, and I can use the [MapDialogRect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645502.aspx) to convert the dialog units to the pixels, How can I do the reverse? the `MoveWindow()` and the `SetWindowPos()` can set eh size of the dialog but not the **default** size. I also have tried the [GetDialogBaseUnits()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) like this:

```
DWORD dw = GetDialogBaseUnits();
WORD m_duXx4 = LOWORD(dw);
WORD m_duYx8 = HIWORD(dw);
int dialogUnitX = MulDiv(640, 4, m_duXx4);
int dialogUnitY = MulDiv(384, 8, m_duYx8);
```

it turned out that the `dialogUnitX` is `320` and the `dialogUnitY` is `192`, but when I set the dialog unit to `320 * 192`, what I got in `CXXXDlg::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)` is not `640 * 384` but `560 * 336`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A window consists of a *Client Area* and a *Nonclient Area*.

The *client area* is the part of a window where the application displays output, such as text or graphics.

The title bar, menu bar, window menu, minimize and maximize buttons, sizing border, and scroll bars are referred to collectively as the window's *nonclient area*.

The *Window Rect* designates the area that encompasses the entire window. It includes the client area as well as the nonclient area. It can be retrieved by calling [`GetWindowRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519.aspx) (or its MFC-equivalent). It is also used as the input to functions like [`MoveWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633534.aspx) or [`SetWindowPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545.aspx).

The *Client Rect* is the area of a window that is not occupied by the nonclient area. It can be queried by calling [`GetClientRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633503.aspx). The client rect dimensions are passed to the [`WM_SIZE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632646.aspx) message handler.

If an application requires a specific size for its client area it can calculate the respective window rect by calling [`AdjustWindowRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632665.aspx) or [`AdjustWindowRectEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632667.aspx).

The window rect is usually expressed in *Screen Coordinates* while the client rect uses *Client Coordinates*. Both coordinate systems represent device pixels. The origin is in the top left corner of the primary display for screen coordinates and the top left corner of the client area for client coordinates. To translate between the coordinate systems an application uses [`ClientToScreen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183434.aspx) or [`ScreenToClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162952.aspx).

Dialog templates specify dimensions and positions in *Dialog Template Units*. Dialog template units are directly related to a dialog's font. To convert between dialog template units and device pixels an application calls [`MapDialogRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645502.aspx). There is no API call to calculate the reverse. An application has to perform the calculations manually:

```
width  = MulDiv(width,  4, baseunitX);
height = MulDiv(height, 8, baseunitY);
```

If an application wants to confine the window size dynamically it can handle the [`WM_GETMINMAXINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632626.aspx) message and populate a [`MINMAXINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632605.aspx) structure with the desired dimensions. This message is sent to a window when the size or position of the window is about to change.